# CodeDOM compilation no errors but fails to launch console

Tags: c#, codedom

I have created my project and now want to compile using a CodeDOM compiler.
I have a folder full of the .CS files that should be compiled to an EXE. The application is supposed to be a console application although it fails to launch any console. There are no building errors. The following is my compile method:

```
public static void Build(string AssemblyName, string OutputDirectory, string[] SourceFiles)
        {
            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
            parameters.OutputAssembly = OutputDirectory + @"\" + AssemblyName + ".exe";
            parameters.CompilerOptions = "/unsafe /target:winexe /platform:x86";

            if (codeProvider.Supports(GeneratorSupport.EntryPointMethod))
            {
                parameters.MainClass = "MyApp.Program";
            }

            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, SourceFiles);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                    Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
            }
        }
```

`string[] SourceFiles` correctly provides all .CS files (classes, structs and enums) located in the folder like follows:

```
"D:\\Development\\MyAppCodeDom\\Program.cs"
"D:\\Development\\MyAppCodeDom\\IniParser.cs"
```

And 26 more of those. I do not use any external DLL files as reference whatsoever. It fails, however, to launch the console window.

Any idea? Perhaps a console application requires certain options?

**EDIT:**
Using ILSpy, the assembly seems to contain ALL the classes etc it should have.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It creates the .exe? And you're double clicking on the .exe? Nothing about the code listed above says to actually run the assembly...

Comment: Figured it out. Removed /target:winexe - now it works all fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed /target:winexe from the CompilerOptions and now it works.